# How to insert value into Lookup Field of the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to insert or update value to the lookup field of the crm dynamics form. 
In code below I am getting the lookup value from one form and trying to insert or update that value to crm dynamics form's lookup field. Lookup field of both forms have the same name which is "Co".
I guess I do not understand the proper logic of how can I achieve this. All my guess is it would be through object and guid value to update lookup field of crm dynamics form.
Code is written below and it is getting the lookup value from the form. What Can I do now to insert that lookup value into another form? Anyone please help me in this? Thanks

```
    //getting the lookup value using code below

namespace L.C.CPS {

    public partial class CRD {  

        private System.Guid cIdField; 
        private string cNameField; 

        public System.Guid CId {
            get {
                return this.cIdField;
            }
            set {
                this.cIdField = value;
            }
        }

        public string CName {
            get {
                return this.cNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.cNameField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

//getting the lookup value using code below

namespace L.C.CPS {

    public partial class XED{

        private CRD cField;      

        public CRD Co {
            get {
                return this.cField;
            }
            set {
                this.cField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

//using code below to insert or update the lookup value of another form by using the values from above code.

using L.C.CPS;
using System;

namespace MP.C.F.S {
    public class USR :  ISAction {

        public string Co { get; set; }


        public void Execute(ID formid, ARList fields, params object[] data) {
           XED A = new XED {
                   Co = Co  // This is where I like to add my logic
           };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Values aren't moved from one form to another, they're read and written to and from the database.

Your code will be written within a plugin. See Microsoft's [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx#BKMK_getText) here. You must register your plugin against an event (when you want the plugin to fire). For example this could be when one of the lookup fields changes.

To get the value of a lookup field, you would write:

```
entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("lookupAttribute");
```

To set the value of a lookup field, you would write:

```
entity.Attributes.Add(new EntityReference(Guid, "entityName"));
```

More on GetAttributeValue can be read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx).